# ML integration with WSO2 Data Analytics Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-ml

I tried in ML 1.1.0 create a new dataset from DAS, but the response is empty, for some reason the table/events in DAS not show in ML. I reviewed this documentation ( https://docs.wso2.com/display/ML100/Integration+with+WSO2+Data+Analytics+Server) but any result. I tested api /api/configs/das/tables and response is empty []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question, it is not clear which DAS version you are testing with WSO2 ML.

Assuming you are using WSO2 DAS 3.0.0:

I tested this scenario using the embedded database (i.e. H2) which comes with WSO2 products. Also, please note that uploading data from DAS server  works irrespective of the database system which configures with DAS and ML.

So in order to help you to debug your issue, I would like to highlight following points.

1. Did you properly configure all three databases, namely: 
   `WSO2_ANALYTICS_FS_DB`, `WSO2_ANALYTICS_EVENT_STORE_DB` and `WSO2_ANALYTICS_PROCESSED_DATA_STORE_DB`. Please note that data sources in both ML and DAS should be pointed to the same database. For instance, data source `WSO2_ANALYTICS_FS_DB` in both ML and DAS should be correctly pointed to the same database.
2. Next, start both servers ( If you are running both servers on the same machine you have to offset ports in one of the servers).
3. Now go to your DAS server and create a test table.
4. Next, if you go to "Create Dataset" page, you will be able to see the newly created data table.

However, if you are using WSO2 DAS 3.0.1:

Presently, create dataset using DAS tables feature is not working with DAS 3.0.1. We have created a public JIRA [1] for this issues and once this is fixed we will notify you.

[1]. https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ML-312

Comment: Your answer is correct and so marked. But is that the documentation is unclear. I'm using Cassandra and had to go to analytics-config and make modifications there to say not to use the RDBMS and to use cassandra.

Comment: If creating a dataset using DAS tables feature is not working with WSO2 DAS 3.0.1, how can I create a data table in WSO2 DAS in the first place so that I can later connect to it from WSO2 ML?